# Can we use windows bat file in Java jar file, so that java can run some windows command, if yes where we should keep bat file in side that jar file

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, process

I am trying to execute a windows command inside java code using Runtime.exec() command. It is working fine when put all the necessary batch file and properties file on the root directory. But when i am exporting this is as jar, the java program is throwing error, which is becuase it is not able to find all those dependent .bat and .properties files. Can some one please tell me, where should i keep all the .bat and .properties files in side the folder. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried in `src/main/resources`?

Comment: is the .bat file is changed or not?

Comment: Turbut Alin, I have tried it but no result, the jar file is throwing an error while executing, could you please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so

Something like

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start yourFile.bat");
```

You should be able to keep it in the root of your jar if you want

EDIT :

On second thought I don't think you can run bat files inside a JAR

you would have to extract it and then run it

Please give more information on what it is you want the bat file to be doing and I can update this answer maybe there is another way?

Comment: Hi Jacques Ramsden,

Comment: Hi Jacques Ramsden, I am trying to execute a windows comamnd(which checks for DAC server status) - "dacCmdLine.bat serversStatus". This command needs all the necessary .bat files(dac_env.bat config.bat) and properties files (dac.Properties) to from a remote directory. So to run, it from java program i keep them in the root folder. When i run the java program from the eclipse it is wokring fine. But when i export the code as jar file and try to execute that from a different location it is throwing an error. Please suggest.

Comment: Ok so if you are needing to use the files then I would suggest doing the following...

Have your jar with all the code it needs create a new folder called serverStatusFiles (Or something) and when you create your jar do not bundle fie files inside the jar put them in that directory and run them from there. Just deploy both the jar and the folder with the files in them at the same time. This way you also dont need to re-deploy a new jar if the bat files ever change.

Does that help?

Comment: hi Jacques Ramsden , i have tried the above procedure, though the cmd command  is running in java but not giving the actual output. I have created the jar file and put that in a folder along with all the necessary bat file. When i run that jar file from that folder it is generating some garbage value and giving the actual output that i want. please suggest. Thanks in Advanc.

Comment: Sorry could you please elaborate what you mean by garbage

Comment: This is the code i am using :                                                                                             Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dacCmdLine.bat serverStatus");
         
          System.out.println("the output stream is "+process.getOutputStream());
          BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));      Output i got: the output stream is java.io.BufferedOutputStream@76b10754 , after following the above mentioend procedure. Please have a look.

Comment: You won't get the results of the cmd process if that is what you where trying to do. Are you seeing the bat file pop up and run?

Comment: Remember to add cmd /c start to the exec call

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be divided into two parts: get the bat from the jarand run it.

To get the bat from the jar, you will have to use the ClassLoader to get a resource. you can achieve this by using the method Class.getResource to get the URL or Class.getResourceAsStream to get an InputStream

Anyway, i dont' think you can run the bat from inside the jar. If you try and fail, my advice is to create a temp file, copy your bat into your temp file and run that file.

P.S: Class.getResource finds file in the classpath. If your file is not in your classpath, you won't be able to find it this way.

EDIT: i add the code i'm using to get resources from a general relative path, given the path exist both starting from you working directory and from the home of your jar. It works, i've been able to just pack every folder i need into the jar and ship the jar to another compute rwhere eveything worked fine.

```
public static URL getResource(String name) {
        if ("jar".equals(Main.class.getResource("Main.class").getProtocol())) {
            return Main.class.getResource(("\\" + name).replace('\\', '/'));
        } else {
            try {
                return (new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\" + name)).toURI().toURL();
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

`Main` is a known class, in this case the class where this static method is. I first use it to get a known url, and see if i am executing from a  jar. If i am, i use the getResource, otherwise i use the File api.

the structure i use is this

```
main_folder\
    res\
    src\
        package\
```

and, in the jar

```
file.jar\
    package\
    res\
```

and i need to use both File api and getResource since in the rist case the `res` folder is not in my classpath. with a different structure probably only the `getResource` method is fine.

This should solve your problem of getting the bat file, you still need to see if you are able to run it, and if you are not, copy everything into a temp file and run the temp file instead.

Comment: Hi bracco23, i have tried the workout , u have mentioned but did receive any fruitful result. Please suggest if anything else possible.